# Can Vue apps be nested?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a monolithic SPA that I'm trying to modularize. The first step was breaking down into individual vue apps. Now I'd like to introduce Vue router and hence need to use Vue components. My main component is still nothing more than a wrapper around two Vue apps.

Is it possible to nest Vue apps inside a component or do I need to convert these apps into components even if they are really singletons and no multi-use is intended?

So basically, is something like this possible where sub-app-N are Vue apps similar to the `app` main app:

```
<div id="app">
    <nav>
        <router-link to="/">Main</router-link>
        <router-link to="/settings">Settings</router-link>
    </nav>
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="main-template">
<div>
    <div id="sub-app-1"></div>
    <div id="sub-app-2"></div>
</div>
</script>

<script>
const routes = [
    { path: "/", component: main },
    { path: "/settings", component: settings },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes // short for `routes: routes`
});

const app = new Vue({
    router
}).$mount('#app');

const subapp1 = new Vue({
  el: '#sub-app-1',
  ...
});

const subapp2 = new Vue({
  el: '#sub-app-2',
  ...
});
</script>
```

Comment: Technically you can mount as many VueJS apps on a page as you can, it doesn't really matter. However, ideally they should be individual components instead of standalone apps? You would have issues if you want to make the two individual apps talk to each other, for example.

Comment: I've updated the example. Seems I cannot use an app inside a component. Still confused how I can have router components that consist of apps (even if not desired from perspective of cleanliness)?